# When a Driver is being evaluated are the final positions of objects finished evaluating?

Tags: python, drivers

When a Driver is being evaluated are the final positions of objects finished evaluating?

Does the Dependency Graph take into account references made in a Driver for a topological sort?
The Blender User wants to get the vector between two objects [A] and [B] after the final positions are determined for a frame. Are the object final location transformations calculated before the driver is evaluated.  Are there any arm twisting techniques to make this happen?

Are there any written references that address this topic?  Perhaps my searching is adequate

When I observe the difference vector in the UI, Blender seems to calc a new answer when I click Update Dependencies as opposed to a frame forward event.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, a few quick tests with dependency cycles and drivers vs constraints suggests its complicated. I'd need to actually look at the code